# Laplace Inverse

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica did not give any out put when i am going to compute Laplace Inverse for  a little bet complected function, Kindly if you have any comment or you advice any code to compute the inverse here..

```
c1 = 1/(s(e^(A1 h) - 1));
c2 = 1/(s (e^(-A1 h) - 1));
A1=√(-(pr ϵ k)(1/((s + ϵ)) - 1) + pr s);
Θ[s_] = c1 ⅇ^(A1 y) + c2 ⅇ^(-A1 y);

InverseLaplaceTransform[Θ[s], s, t]
```

Comment: Your `e`'s should be `E`'s (capital!) because in *Mathematica*, the number $e$ is represented by the capital `E`.  All built-in functions and symbols. in *Mathematica* start with capital letters.

Comment: Thanks for the info but still not warking.

Comment: What have You tried? Post corrected  `Mathematica` code.